# Check if property exists in object

Tags: ruby

**I spent a long time now trying to figure this myself with the help of other questions but failed so I REALLY need to ask this again**

I have the following object in ruby

```
(...)
  :follow_request_sent: 
  :notifications:  
:coordinates: 
:place: 
:contributors: 
:favorite_count: 0
:entities:
  :hashtags:
  - :text: 
    :indices:
(...)
```

This is object **X**. What I want to do is check if **x.place** exists. I've tried barely EVERYTHING. any, ?, include?, with [hash], defined?, (...) but it ALWAYS throws an error "undefined method" when trying to access the property, whether it exists or not. It NEVER works and I don't understand why. This is twitter API btw. Does anyone imagine why? Please do not point me to another answers because basically they all failed.

Comment: What kind of object should this be?

Comment: So this object is a hash? What does `x.class` say?

Comment: Can you tell us what `p x` gets you?

Comment: @AbeVoelker --- !ruby/class 'Twitter::Tweet'

Comment: @ndn #<Twitter::Tweet id=630105969716891648>

Comment: And `x.respond_to?(:place)` returns `false`, but `x.place` returns something?

Comment: @ndn crashes into " undefined method 'place' for #<Twitter::Tweet id=630105969716891648>

Comment: Then it doesn't have a `place` and that is why you get `false` returned. You want to access something that doesn't exist? What is your question?

Comment: @ndn I'm not accessing place, I want "quoted_status". When it exists it extends to a new branch of object. Whenever I try to access it, I cant. And it exists alright. Here is the pastebin of that tweet id in particular: http://pastebin.com/Q7yS3iJH

Comment: This is the first time you mention `quoted_status`, but it doesn't matter if it is it, or `place`. "When it exists it extends to a new branch of object. " what does that even mean? Also the snippet you sent isn't the same thing as whatever object you are trying to call methods on.

Comment: @ndn it goes deeper in the branch as in "layers of information". And yes, that is object 'x'. I can access x.text, x.source, x.whatever but can't access x.quoted_status or it crashes as long as everything related with it...

Comment: Try this: what does `x.methods - Object.instance_methods` get you?

Comment: @ndn x.methods http://pastebin.com/uUxZKDXq

Comment: @ndn https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/tweet.rb contains alias_methods for quoted_tweet? and quoted_status? ... :x I'm getting lost

Comment: Sigh... can you post a bigger part of you code please. Also this question should be called "Twitter API not returning quoted_status" as you weren't asking about ruby in general.

Comment: Looking into it further, [`Twitter::Base`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/b299925d22d9ccf75c50328cea34e3f0194e1a33/lib/twitter/base.rb#L17) dynamically defines methods depending on what is in `@attrs`. `Twitter::Tweet` extends `Twitter::Base` by extending `Twitter::Identity`. So the `alias_method :quoted_tweet, :quoted_status` will define an alias if there was a dynamically defined `quoted_status` method to begin with.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to see if there is such a method:

```
x.respond_to?(:place)
```

If you want to see if there is an instance variable:

```
x.instance_variable_defined?(:@place)
```

Comment: :place like a constant? or a string?

Comment: `:place` is a symbol. A ruby construct similar to strings. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html